# Why is there a censoring sound in episode 6?

Tags: no-game-no-life

In [11:25 of episode 6](http://www.crunchyroll.com/no-game-no-life/episode-6-interesting-653173), there is a bleep sound, but I don't know why is it being censored. Jibril and Steph are surprised by it, so would it be a dirty joke or something else?

[image: bleeped sound 11:25]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a reason why Jibril and Steph are surprised in this situation. As you should know Steph and Jibril are girls, so the question would be "what is a girl's nether region?". It is obvious that a girl's nether region would be their:

> Vagina

From [otaku - Censorship](http://otaku.wikispaces.com/Censorship):

As this is considered as a dirty joke, it is censored because `ま☆こ` in direct translation does mean "Nether Regions". If there is no censorship in this scene, it would violate "Japanese Censorship Law". When it is uncensored the word would be `まんこ` (romanized as 
"manko") which directly means vagina.

Hence, the censorship in episode 6 of No Game No Life.

Answer (score 9):

The Japanese text there is ま★こ *ma*ko*, which (to someone who knows Japanese) is obviously a censored form of まんこ *manko*, which does refer to the female genitalia, as Sukeibe points out.

The key insight here is that *manko* is in fact **vulgar** slang for the female genitalia, which is why you will see it censored. The translation "nether regions" fails to capture this vulgarity, I suppose because it's constrained by the rules of word chain (can you think of a vulgar term for the female genitalia that begins with "n" and ends with "s"? I can't...). If a technical/medical term for the female genitalia were used instead (e.g. 女性器 *joseiki* lit. "female sex organ"), it would probably not have been censored.

Comment: Wait a second, does that mean that from that point on in the game, Shiro, Steph, and Jibril's vagina dissapeared?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Well, I guess. If you jump to ~12:50 in episode 6, you see that the three of them have Barbie-doll-style anatomy at that point.